# Tabs - Retornar para aba desejada

Tags: c#, html

Bom dia, pessoal! No meu cadastro de Fornecedores, na View Details, eu tenho uma Tab com as abas: Dados, Contatos e Compras, e quando eu clico na aba Contatos, há um botão para cadastrar novo contato e me direciona para a View Contatos dos Fornecedores.
Ao cadastrar o novo contato, preciso fazer retornar para a View Details dos Fornecedores, porém na aba Contatos.
Minha Tab da View Details dos Fornecedores esta assim:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-dados" data-toggle="tab" href="#dados" role="tab" aria-controls="dados" aria-selected="true">Dados</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contatos-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contatos" role="tab" aria-controls="contatos" aria-selected="false">Contatos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="compras-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#compras" role="tab" aria-controls="compras" aria-selected="false">Compras</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="dados" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dados-tab">Exibe os dados do Fornecedor</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contatos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contatos-tab">
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
            <tr>
                <th>Tipo do contato</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telefone</td>
                <td>9999-8888</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>oxoxoxoxo.com.br</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <button type="button"
                title="Novo registro"
                class="btn"
                style="background-color: lightsteelblue;"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "ContatoFornecedores", new { FornecedorId = @TempData["FornecedorId"] })'">
            Novo Contato
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="compras" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="compras-tab">Exibe todas as compras efetuadas junto ao Fornecedor</div>
</div>
```

Qual a maneira que dá pra se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Pensei em colocar mais um parâmetro no onclick, ficando assim:

```
onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Fornecedores", new { id = @TempData["FornecedorId"], selectTab = 2})'">
```

Aí, quando retorna à View Details do Fornecedor, a url fica assim:

http://localhost:61801/Fornecedores/Details/9?selectTab=1

Agora precisava de uma maneira de pegar essa selectedTab no Controller e enviar para a View para abrir a aba que eu quero. Pensei em fazer assim:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, int? selectedTab)
{
    if (selectedTab == null)
    {
       TempData["SelectedTab"] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       TempData["SelectedTab"] = selectedTab;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Será que estou indo pelo caminho certo?
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?